# RxJS: applying timeout operator to only part of a sequence

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm using RxJS Observables to handle the flow multiple events serially. I would like to first listen for `event1`, then wait for `event2` once, then complete. I need to make sure that `event1` is emitted first within 1s (and throw an error if not). The `.timeout` operator is perfect for this. However, afterwards I need to allow for waiting for `event2` indefinitely.

Here's what I've tried:

```
  const windowMessage$ = Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent(window, 'message')
    .publish()
    .refCount();

  const event1$ = windowMessage$.filter(e => e.data && e.data.type === 'event1');
  const event2$ = windowMessage$.filter(e => e.data && e.data.type === 'event2');

  const source$ = event1$
    .timeout(1000)
    .switchMap(event2$)
    .take(1);

  source$.subscribe(
    data => console.log('got data', data),
    console.error.bind(console),
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
```

This will consistently result in a *Timeout Error* since `event2` is (expectedly) not being emitted within 1s. 
I'm guessing that the problem is that the `.timeout` operator is indifferent to where it is in the chain.

I realize that an alternative might be to use a `.race()` operator to make sure `event1` is coming in sooner than 1s, however I'm currently using RxJS v4 which does not have `.race`.

Comment: The RxJS v4 equivalent of race is amb, and is exactly what I thought of when I read the title of your question.

Comment: The timeout operator only applies to the first event. The problem must be the first event not fireing. Tap on the event stream to see what,s happening.